# Shifting HEC RAS cross sections to the side

Tags: cross-section, hec-ras

I was wondering if there is a way to shift a cross section in HEC RAS to the side?
Since my data is not the best, a lot of xs are shifted somehow (see screenshot). The only way fixing it I found so far is opening and editing (shifting) the entire xs in RASMapper, then going back to the xs editor, checking whether the shifting is okay and depending on whether it does not look fine redoing it several times.
Would be okay when only having a bunch of xs, but the model includes hundreds of xs...

Does anyone has an idea?
(edit: I added a second example)

[image]

[image]

Comment: But that section does not need to be shifted, it needs to be swapped. Hec-ras requires all sections to be drawn from left to right looking downstream.

Comment: You did not state how you are working, I guess your project is georeferenced and the cross sections are produced out of a terrain model in ras mapper. In case you start with a gis file with the cross sections it is easy to swap them in your GIS program. I do that regularly in QGIS with a plugin

Comment: I know how to fix this (swap cross sections) with QGIS and RiverGIS, will it work for you?

Comment: Swapped, you mean mirrored? Actually the cross sections come from measured (badly measured) xyz-data. Even it looks like swapped, it is not. I will add another example that maybe shows it clearer...

Comment: In the picture you are comparing the data of the cross section itself (black line with dots) with data from a terrain model in rasmapper. Is it that terrain model build out of the same survay? I still guess they are morrered. Why are you sure they are not?

Comment: Exactly. The terrain and the measured cross sections have a different source and year of recording. Well, I cannot be completely certain that the cross sections aren't mirrored since I did not record the data myself, but I received the data as xyz-data, so I assume the z-value corresponds to the right coordinates, even the accuracy of positioning may not be the best.

Comment: I now started to expand the cut lines on each side to get a better view of the terrain in the XS editor and adjusting the cross section coordinates via adding or subtracting values to the station... I will use the cross sections to burn the channel into the DEM later..

Comment: In practice you do not need to fix anything. The 1d calculation does not care about the mirroring of the cross section, the water level will be exactly the same unless you have different roughness. The flood mapping will not change if you keep your existing terrain, but it is hard to advise you without knowing the real extend and purpose of your work. Be aware that the cross section migh have a different length in the cross section (calculations) than in the gis representation, be cautioned at that

Comment: Thanks Marco. I use the XS to burn the channel into the DTM. In the end I would like to use the modified terrain for a 2d calculation.